# Clone add_more button in custom content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I create a bundle with the [paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module and add it to a content type.

Is there a way to duplicate the "add-more" button so I can click on it on the top and the bottom of the page? I want to have this button present one in the top of the page and one in the bottom.
I try to deal with the function `field_multiple_value_form()` but I don't know how to make it works.

[image]

---

I think I express myself badly.

I created a new content type (*News*) and in it I put a field type (*paragraph*).
This field can contain as many buttons you want, cannot it?
I want to repeat these buttons at the top and bottom of the *News* content type, not in the form that structures the paragraph itself as shown on the picture above.

Comment: You can achieve this using the form API. To make it work exactly the same as the other one you should be able to just use the same ajax callback and wrapper on a new button. Check out [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)

Comment: Thanks for your help kiamlaluno but I think I express myself badly, and i am sorry for that. In fact this is what I want to do: I create a new content type named "News" and in it I put a field type "paragraph". This field "paragraph" can contain as many buttons you want right? And it is these buttons that I want to repeat at the top and bottom of content type "News" page (not in the form that strucutre the paragraph itself as shown on the picture above).

Thank you for your help.